# Count Events/year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a list of events that have a date. I'm trying to count how many events take place in the current year, and 5 years on either side (regardless of whether any events took place) in mySQL using simple joins, selects, etc (no subqueries) in a single statement.

I have a table that produces the years and the number of events in that year, but am having problems when the year has no events taking place

Comment: You might want to provide some of what you have done already.  Table design, what you have tried that didn't work, etc.  Most people are not going to go out of their way to help you if you haven't at least tried, and with out showing what you have tried, a lot of people are just going to assume that you haven't and not help.

Comment: ya that makes sense. sorry bout that. I had a worse way of achieving the same thing as rich.okelly posted. I'm having trouble displaying years with no events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into date functions on mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

You can use datediff which will give you difference in days. Ex;

WHERE abs(datediff(now(), event_date)) < 365*5

or dateadd(), if your event dates are timestamps, use timestampdiff()

Sample query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable
WHERE abs(datediff(now(), event_date)) < 365*5
```

**UPDATE**

based on some of the comments I've read here, here's a query for you

```
SELECT year(event_date) as event_year, count(event_date)
FROM mytable
WHERE
abs(datediff(now(), event_date)) < 365*5
GROUP by year(event_date)
```

Feel free to adjust 5 in (365 * 5) for different range

**UPDATE 2**

This is NOT very pretty but you can try this with pure mysql. You can also modify this to be a stored proc if necessary:

```
SET @y6 = year(now());
SET @y5 = @y6-1;
SET @y4 = @y5-1;
SET @y3 = @y4-1;
SET @y2 = @y3-1;
SET @y1 = @y2-1;

SET @y7 = @y6+1;
SET @y8 = @y7+1;
SET @y9 = @y8+1;
SET @y10 = @y9+1;
SET @y11 = @y10+1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE event_years (event_year int not null);
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y1;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y2;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y3;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y4;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y5;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y6;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y7;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y8;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y9;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y10;
INSERT INTO event_years SELECT @y11;

SELECT ey.event_year , (SELECT count(event_date) from mytable where year(event_date) = ey.event_year)
from event_years ey;
```

temporary table will get dropped by itself after your connection is closed. If you add DROP TABLE after SELECT, you might not get your results back.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. The problem I'm having is say I have an event in 2008 and and event in 2014, but no other years. Only those years will show in the table. all the other years within the range 2006-2016 won't show up

Comment: @Ronald Dregan, take a look at the updated answer. Not pretty but functional

Answer (score 0):

To select a count of events that happened between two years, grouped by years, the following sql should suffice:

```
select year(event.date), count(*) from event where event.date >= '2006' and event.date <= '2016' group by year(event.date);
```

However, if no events occurred in a year, no result will be returned for it.
Databases are not really designed for such dynamic things and I'd suggest such logic should be put in a business (or possibly data-access) layer.

Comment: This method is helpful (achieves the same thing I had, but cleaner) but I still run into problems in the same place I was before I post. 

I can't seem to get it to show years where the number of events would be 0

Comment: You are selecting events. If no event.date has the year 'abcd', then 'abcd' can never be in the output. You will probably need to handle this in code; iterate over a sequence of years that you generate, and if that year is not represented in the db output, the count is zero.

Comment: Is there a way to run some sort of join on an ENUM created "on the fly". Like

FROM Event JOIN (ENUM = range of years)

Comment: This is not an answer, it is just code. Without explanations it doesn't contribute enough to the Wiki. Please improve or delete it.

Comment: Despite not having an explanation I found this answer helpful

Comment: @markus You are right, I intended to expand upon my answer but got sidetracked. Now updated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use join left?

**MODIFIED:**

```
SELECT tleft.YEARS, COUNT(tright.EVENTS) 
FROM ONLY_YEARS tleft LEFT JOIN TABLE1 tright 
ON (tleft.YEARS = tright.YEARS)
GROUP BY tleft.YEARS;
```

With that modification, you need to point to a table that holds all the years (ONLY_YEARS), maybe a dummy table with one column that goes from 1990 to 2020...

[Left join optimization for MySQL link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Comment: I don't have, and can't create a table of years

Comment: I'm pointing to the column YEARS inside TABLE1, what I do I join left the table with itself by giving two different names, then I list all the years in TABLE1 and then I count the EVENTS also in TABLE1 but with another name (it's quite confusing, I know)

Comment: after toying around with it a bit I got it to produce the same thing I had, but still am not sure this solves the issue of displaying a year where no events happened. I'm having problems making the column of years because some of the years don't exist in the events. does that make sense?

Comment: Now yes, we can only play with data that is in the table, if the year doesn't exist we can't make it up, so maybe you need to get a table with the years listed and left join them with the events.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow create this year list? something like:

FROM (somehow create list) LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 tright

Comment: I need to check that option, btw I updated my solution by adding another table with only the years listed

Comment: if you are using mysql, i got this [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/autoincrement-value-mysql/) that may can help. I'll get you back with a potential solution